# Combining two simple harmonic motion in perpendicular directions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, mathematics

So, I was studying about the combination of two simple harmonic motions (S.H.M.) in the perpendicular direction withstand frequency, but with different amplitude and phases; and, I also studied the graphs in the X-Y plane, depicting the motion of a particle under the influence of forces corresponding to the above S.H.M., which looked like this [image]

Assuming, that the values of the parameters is not needed here, as it is for representation purpose only.

I know that this absolutely doesn't look like an ellipse, but being a mathematics student, I would be only satisfied by a formal proof that this graph is not an ellipse.

Hence, my question is: **how would you go on proving that the above graph is not an ellipse?**

Comment: What if it's an ellipse? Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146477/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/633043/226902

Comment: Your answer is here: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton/node28.html (see Figure 10).

Comment: If the frequencies are the same, then it is an ellipse. It’s the 2D projection of a circle in the 4D phase space.

Comment: @Quillo thanks for the reference of that site because that's the only one I needed.

Comment: @lpz could you please elaborate your answer as I think from your answer I would get a new way of thinking for this problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve : "For a ratio of 1, when the frequencies match a=b, the figure is an ellipse"

Answer (score 2):

*This is an ellipse*. Suppose for simplicity that the phase shift is $\pi/2$:
$$
x(t)=A\cos(\omega t + \phi),\\
y(t)=B\sin(\omega t +\phi),
$$
then
$$
\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}=1,
$$
which is an equation for an ellipse.
I suggest doing the case of unequal phases as an exercise (hint: express $\sin(\omega t),\cos(\omega t)$ in terms of $x,y$, and employ again the main trigonometric identity.)

Answer (score 0):

Making everything dimensionless, your system of ODE's are:
$$
\ddot x +x=0 \\
\ddot y +y=0
$$
in the $\mathbb R^2$ configuration space. Naturally, you go to $\mathbb R^4$ phase space:
$$
\dot x = p \\
\dot p = -x \\
\dot y = q \\
\dot q = -y
$$
It is more convenient to identify $\mathbb R^4$ with $\mathbb C^2$ with:
$$
z = x+ip \\
w = y+iq
$$
giving:
$$
\dot z = -iz \\
\dot w = -iw
$$
This makes more apparent the conservation laws. With $z_0,w_0$ the initial conditions, there is conservation of energy:
$$
|z_0|^2+|w_0|^2 = |z|^2+|w|^2
$$
so geometrically, trajectories are in a hypersphere $\mathbb S^3$. There is also:
$$
w_0z-z_0w = 0
$$
so geometrically, trajectories are in a plane going through the origin. Trajectories lie in the intersection of a hypersphere and plane going through its origin, they are therefore circles of the same radius. You then project them onto the $x,y$ plane, which gives an ellipse.

If you're into math, this is exactly the [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration). You are essentially decomposing the energy hypersphere into circular trajectories. The "quotient" can be identified algebraically with the ratio $z_0/w_0$ with an extra point for the case $w_0 = 0$, which, topologically, is the same as the sphere $\mathbb S^2$.

Hope this helps.